# Does virtualenv serve a purpose (in production) when using docker?

Tags: python, virtualenv, docker

For development we use virtualenv to have an isolated development when it comes to dependencies. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337149/is-virtualenv-recommended-for-django-production-server) it seems deploying Python applications in a [virtualenv](/questions/tagged/virtualenv) is recommended.

Now we're starting to use [docker](/questions/tagged/docker) for deployment. This provides a more isolated environment so I'm questioning the use of virtualenv inside a docker container. In the case of a single application I do not think virtualenv has a purpose as docker already provides isolation. In the case where multiple applications are deployed on a single docker container, I do think virtualenv has a purpose as the applications can have conflicting dependencies.

Should virtualenv be used when a single application is deployed in a docker container?

Should docker contain multiple applications or only one application per container?

If so, should virtualenv be used when deploying a container with multiple applications?

Comment: I think you got the right questions. When having a set of python applications to work on at the same time, you'll need virtualenv to avoid browsing from container to container ... I'ld recommend to use virtualenv by default even though the container is just dedicated to work on a single app because ... well you never know. And the overhead induced by virtualenv is not that high :)

Comment: @Rerito There is no overhead of using docker. Its simply a chroot jail on linux.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Virtualenv was created long before docker. Today, I lean towards docker instead of virtualenv for these reasons:

- Virtualenv still means people consuming your product need to download eggs. With docker, they get something which is "known to work". No strings attached.
- Docker can do much more than virtualenv (like create a clean environment when you have products that need different Python versions).

The main drawback for Docker was the poor Windows support. That changed with the version for Windows 10.

As for "how many apps per container", the usual policy is 1.

Comment: To use docker on Windows (or OS X) I'd recommend [boot2docker](http://boot2docker.io/).

Comment: 5s is pretty fast to boot docker on Windows but it's still about 100 times slower than the average start times on Linux :-)

Comment: are those points still applicable to docker ? (poor windows support)

Comment: @Ani No, as of Nov 2017, I'd say Windows 10 and Linux docker are almost on par.

Comment: I'm updating on 2018 currently Windows support is the same as in UNIX based OS.

Comment: I think Docker also makes it easier to, say, switch databases later  as well because you can just spin up a Docker container for your DB (or new system component).

Answer (score 40):

Yes. You should still use virtualenv. Also, you should be building wheels instead of eggs now. Finally, you should make sure that you keep your Docker image lean and efficient by building your wheels in a container with the full build tools and installing no build tools into your application container.

You should read this excellent article. https://glyph.twistedmatrix.com/2015/03/docker-deploy-double-dutch.html

The key take away is

> It’s true that in many cases, perhaps even most, simply installing
>   stuff into the system Python with Pip works fine; however, for more
>   elaborate applications, you may end up wanting to invoke a tool
>   provided by your base container that is implemented in Python, but
>   which requires dependencies managed by the host. By putting things
>   into a virtualenv regardless, we keep the things set up by the base
>   image’s package system tidily separated from the things our
>   application is building, which means that there should be no unforeseen
>   interactions, regardless of how complex the application’s usage of
>   Python might be.

Comment: [PEP370](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/) Introduced the --user flag (in 2008) that allows the installation of packages in  $HOME. This takes care of 99% of use-cases that I used to use virtualenv/pyvenv for. Good to keep in mind, I think.

Comment: I just got a down vote with no comment. How is that helpful to anyone?

Comment: This may be true if you use a bloated container OS like ubuntu which they use in the sample. But if you pick the right OS, like Alpine, this is a non-issue. Alpine ships without Python out of the box, so you know your Python installation is there only because you installed it because your application needs it.

Answer (score 12):

Introducing virtualenv is very easy, so I'd say start without it on your docker container.

If the need arises, then maybe you can install it. Running "pip freeze > requirements.txt" will give you all your python packages. 
However, I doubt you'll ever need virtualenv inside a docker container as creating another container would be a more preferable alternative.

I would not recommend having more than one application in a single container. When you get to this point, your container is doing too much.

Answer (score 2):

I use both because with that you can more easily use [multi stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) and simply move your dependencies you built in one stage into later images/layers. Example can be found [here](https://pmac.io/2019/02/multi-stage-dockerfile-and-python-virtualenv/).

Answer (score 0):

You can replace virtualenv using docker.  Just create different Dockerfiles for different environments and use ports and volumes as needed for the environments.

Here's an [example project](https://github.com/abhijit838/falcon-example-docker-env). Run `docker compose` and start coding.
Write your own Dockerfiles for different environments like test, staging and production by putting your log and data in volumes.

This link is also useful https://vsupalov.com/docker-python-development/.